# ASP.NET MVC - Why does my table have so many columns?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a UserCalendar model defined with a `string UserID` and an `int EventID`. My ApplicationDbContext class contains a declaration of a `DbSet` of UserCalendars called `Calendars`. Somehow, the create-table statement for the Calendars table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Calendars] (
    [Id]                   NVARCHAR (450)     NOT NULL,
    [AccessFailedCount]    INT                NOT NULL,
    [ConcurrencyStamp]     NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [Email]                NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [EmailConfirmed]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [EventID]              INT                NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnabled]       BIT                NOT NULL,
    [LockoutEnd]           DATETIMEOFFSET (7) NULL,
    [NormalizedEmail]      NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [NormalizedUserName]   NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PasswordHash]         NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumber]          NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [PhoneNumberConfirmed] BIT                NOT NULL,
    [SecurityStamp]        NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    [TwoFactorEnabled]     BIT                NOT NULL,
    [UserID]               NVARCHAR (MAX)     NOT NULL,
    [UserName]             NVARCHAR (MAX)     NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_Calendars] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

I believe that these excess columns are preventing me from adding any records to the table, as the vast majority are meaningless; Calendars is a link between users and events, and so only the foreign keys are necessary.

What caused the create-table statement to include the excess columns, and how can it be resolved?

```
public class UserCalendar
{
    [Required]
    public int UserCalendarID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EventID { get; set; }
}


public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
    public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Event> Events { get; set; }
    public DbSet<ApplicationUser> Artists { get; set; }
    public DbSet<UserCalendar> Calendars { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE: The UserCalendar class originally inherited from IdentityUser. This has now been fixed. The following error message is now created when attempting to run Update-Database with a fresh migration:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: The object 'PK_Calendars' is dependent on column 'ID'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID failed because one or more objects access this column.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite, String methodName)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.Execute(IRelationalConnection connection, String executeMethod, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues, Boolean closeConnection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Internal.RelationalCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(IRelationalConnection connection, IReadOnlyDictionary`2 parameterValues)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.MigrationCommandExecutor.ExecuteNonQuery(IEnumerable`1 migrationCommands, IRelationalConnection connection)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_1.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
ClientConnectionId:90d49e6f-8365-4355-9470-fcf2745bb91b
Error Number:5074,State:1,Class:16
The object 'PK_Calendars' is dependent on column 'ID'.
ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN ID failed because one or more objects access this column.
```

An attempt to drop the table has been made with the following migration, but this produces the same error:

```
   public partial class dropCalMig : Migration
    {
        protected override void Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.DropTable(
                name: "Calendars");
        }

        protected override void Down(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder)
        {
            migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "Calendars",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    UserCalendarID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
                        .Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn),
                    EventID = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    UserID = table.Column<string>(nullable: false)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                    table.PrimaryKey("PK_Calendars", x => x.UserCalendarID);
                });
        }
    }
```

Comment: The fields you are getting are from the IdentityUser object. why is your 'link' table inheriting from that class?

Comment: ...because I pasted the template from another class without thinking. The inheritance has now been removed.

Comment: When you say 'fresh migration', do you mean that you have no needed data in any of the tables and you want to create a new database, and you're using EF code first with sql server? If so, first detach the database, next delete the database files (2 files, .mdf and .ldf), and try your migration again.

Comment: I do not in fact mean there is no data in any tables; only Calendars is empty. I suppose I should have said "new" instead of "fresh," meaning that it was created after fixing the inheritance issue.

Comment: You may need to create a new migration that drops the table and recreates it. Have you looked at the table's actual fields? You might find that the ID is still present in your actual table.

Comment: The ID values are present, yes, but it made most of the other values non-nullable and I have no source for them.

Comment: Dropping the table produces the same error on update.

Comment: Does your db contain [dbo].[Calendars] and [dbo].[UserCalendar]?

Comment: There is no UserCalendar table, only Calendars. I'm adding the dropCal migration to the post.